# Bitcoin-qt to input.io no confirmations

Tags: transactions, revert-transaction

I sent 2.4 BTC from the vanilla bitcoin client to my input.io wallet.  The bitcoin-qt client didn't ask for any fees and sent instantly. In transaction details it shows 0/3 confirmation and no transmitting nodes. My input.io wallet does not show any unconfirmed balance.  It has been 2 hours. What happens next? Did I lose my bitcoin?

```
Status: 0/unconfirmed
Date: 8/4/13 13:06
To: input.io 1QGd7qen3Qj6mht7ikmbHiKsLYgF3cEuWN
Debit: -2.40129 BTC
Net amount: -2.40129 BTC
Transaction ID: 30600040f3bac94fa4fff1f990d36f15434d3e0074cb5c919dc63fb34f578ce9
```

Comment: Your transaction now has five confirmations.

Comment: https://blockchain.info/tx/30600040f3bac94fa4fff1f990d36f15434d3e0074cb5c919dc63fb34f578ce9